# Problemas con thunder client

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vscode, npm, postman

Estoy usando la libreria de JSON server y al momento de usar thunder client con la ip del localhost no me arroja resultados y me arroja: "Connection was refused by the server."
Cuando uso Postman, si me arroja los datos en JSON, quisiera saber a que se debe el motivo por el cual no me arroja los datos.
[image: Resultado en VSCode]

[image: Datos en PostMan]